# I couldn't open database file Lil2.bib : \bibdata{Lil2 : }

Tags: bibliographies, overleaf

I currently use overleaf online.
I suddenly meet this problem.
I did not change anything from the bib file....
It worked fine yesterday.
I am not sure if this is the problem with bibliographystyle.
I have searched this issue online, and I saw many people encountered this problem and unsolved.

Could you please help me solve this problem?

Thank you for all

Best wishes

`\bibliographystyle{elsarticle-harv} \nocite{*} \bibliography{Lil2}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found that this problem only exists in this specific project. This bug appeared suddenly. The document did not change any settings about the bibliography before the bug appeared.

This is an online co-work project. I checked a lot of information, and I really couldn't solve this problem, so I sent a message to my supervisor. Strangely, It works totally fine on my supervisor's computer. My supervisor copied the same project, and share the new link of the copied project with me. It works fine on my computer now......

No one changed any code in this document in the process.
If you are in the same situation as me, please don't be anxious, **try to get your co-worker to copy the project and send you a new link.**

Unfortunately, I am not a computer professional. I don't know what is causing this problem. Hope someone can answer in the future.

I list below what I have tried while trying to solve this problem. Sadly, none of these methods worked：

1. change a browser:  I change Chrome to edge/ edge dev, not work.
2. Copy the file myself: After I encounter this issue, I copied myself again. the new copy file not works. But the previously copied file works fine. This means after you have the problem already, copying the project won't fix the bug.
3. recompile from scratch
4. re-name the bib/create a new bib: the warning will disappear, but the document still won't load your reference